# Update DB field using Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I'm a n00bie with Zend but I'm learning it.
I want to update a field in the database using a button, but I don't know how to do it.

This is what I wanna do: `UPDATE $table SET content_field=1 WHERE $id = contentId`

For example if I press that button I wanna put a 1 in the field instead of a default 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Client table and created the model

```
$model_client = new Model_Client();
$client = $model_client->find($my_client_row_id)->current();
$client->some_field = 1;
$client->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an update query with this code

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_TableName();
$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $contentId);
$data = array('content_field' => 1);
$table->update($data, $where);
```

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but can I link to the button?
Just because with PHP, I usually do something like that:

<form name="form1" method="post" action="testForm.php">
<input type="Submit" name="Submit1" value="Update">
</form>

and in the PHP file I write the sql actions, but I still don't understand how can I link the button from my view to a real action.

Comment: If you want to enter in the method "updateDataAction" in the controller "User" you need to do the post to

/user/updatedata
 and access the post data with $this->_request->getParam('INPUT_NAME_PARAM');

Is that what you meant?

Comment: I hard coded a form in view/content/myfile.tpl like this:

<form method="post" action="/Admin/"/>
      <select name="content_field">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="0">Yes</option>
      <option value="1">No</option>
   <input value="Go" type="submit" />
  </form>

But I don't know how to "link" that submit button to an Update DB field function like this one:

UPDATE $table SET content_field=1 WHERE $id = contentId

Comment: You have to create a controller ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.quickstart.html ) with inside an action (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html ). Your form should then link to /namecontroller/nameaction and in the method of the action you have to get the posted value (content_field) and execute the code i posted above

Comment: Oh cool, thank you very much.

I'll read up well the pages and hope to fix the problem. Thank you very much for the help.